# Json array encode and decode the same

Tags: php, arrays, json

I encode an array to json format using the code below :

```
$arrayName[] = array('user_role_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1);
$arrayName[] = array('user_role_id' => 2, 'user_id' => 2);

$jos = json_encode(array_values($arrayName));
```

The output is

```
[{"user_role_id":1,"user_id":1},{"user_role_id":2,"user_id":2}]
```

And sent it to browser.

Then after some steps browser returns the same array.

But when I try to decode

```
$return = json_decode($jos,TRUE);
```

I receive the error : Array to string conversion.

Browser didnt do anything to the array. Simply returns what I supply.

Code flow will be like :

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['array']))
{
    $arrayName[] = array('user_role_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1);
    $arrayName[] = array('user_role_id' => 2, 'user_id' => 2);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $jos = json_encode($arrayName);
}
else
{
    if(isset($_POST['jos']))
    {
        $jos = $_POST['jos'];

        echo $new_jos = json_decode($jos,TRUE);
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me?

What might be wrong?

Comment: I tested with $jos = json_encode($arrayName); also. Still no progress.

Comment: Why you need array_values() function?

Comment: where did you set `$jos`?

Comment: `And sent it to browser.` how do you set your json to json_decode?

Comment: Output of `var_dump($jos);` please

Comment: Show us more code. `Array to string conversion` cannot possibly occur with `json_decode()`. Are you `echo`ing the `$return` variable, or pass it to any function that expects a string?

Comment: @BartoszZasada if you pass an array to json_decode instead of an string, you would get this error - so he set jos to an wrong value

Comment: Show all the code

Comment: Thank you all for the reply.

full code will be like this: 

`if(isset($_GET['array']))
{
 $arrayName[] = array('user_role_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1);
 $arrayName[] = array('user_role_id' => 2, 'user_id' => 2);

 echo $jos = json_encode($arrayName);
}
else
{
 if(isset($_POST['jos']))
 {
  $jos = $_POST['jos'];

  echo $new_jos = json_decode($jos,TRUE);
 }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
echo $new_jos = json_decode($jos,TRUE);
```

so you convert your json string to an array(that works!) and then echo it - that is what throws the error.

Just use

```
$new_jos = json_decode($jos,TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks. echo was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below line in PHP file you receive data from browser and then try to decode.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```